# SetFrom PHPMailer not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using gmail SMTP to send the mail with the help of phpmailer library. It is sending mails fine but it is not sending from the mail address that I am setting in SetFrom address. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "myusername@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "gmail_password";

$mail->From         = 'donotreply@mydomain.com';
$mail->FromName     = 'Admin';
$mail->AddAddress('Toreceiver@test.com', 'Receiver');  // Add a recipient
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the Subject';
$mail->WordWrap = 50;  
$mail->Body = "This is in <b>Blod Text</b>";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

It is sending mail from myusername@gmail.com  but I want it to send with 'donotreply@mydomain.com' as set in $mail->From. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read what google say about [sending email from different addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

Comment: @Anigel : Just suppose, you are making a contact form and sending mail with phpmailer. The from address will be what the user fills in the email address field and toAddress will be your email id. In that case, everytime for different users, fromEmail will always be different. So, we need to set it in $mail->From. Thats what I am doing. I don't think it has to anything from your link's article.

Comment: I don't think you have read the article then, Google say you can only send from addresses that are configured in your google account. You cant just log in as jo.bloggs and send email from jane.doe If you want to do what you have just described, then you cannot use gmail SMTP, you will have to use a different server that allows you to send email as anyone and you will get spam filtered or blocked on many mail servers as YOUR mail server will not match the proper mail server for the users from address IE it will fail SPF checks

Comment: You mean to say that we should not use phpmailer if we are creating a contact form because with it, it can block many mails...

Comment: No I mean that gmail will only allow you to send email from an address that is linked with your google account. It does not matter if you use phpmailer, generic php, c, java or any language as it is a restriction on the google mail server that you are trying to use, not a restriction of phpmailer.

Comment: Thanks Anigel... One more thing for confirmation... Is it the issue with gmail only or with all other mail servers too???

Comment: It is up to the SMTP server administator to determine who it allows to send email through it.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is a Google Mail restriction. The "From" email address must match or is automatically set that way by Google SMTP.

My solution was to add

```php
$mail->AddReplyTo($FromEmail, $FromName);
```

This way at least if you reply to the message it will be delivered as described

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the root cause. If you are on gsuite and you can set up alias, then adding the desired email as an alias will allow you to set that one as the from email address.

Answer (score 7):

There is another way to set from address in phpmailer and it is better supported. I found that server where i used phpmailer didn't pass email to another server from the same host. But then i change the way how i set the from address and it solve the problem.

Use:

```
$mail->SetFrom('donotreply@mydomain.com', 'Admin');
```

Instead of $mail->From and $mail->FromName.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to use different email address as sentFrom, then you can set your email from gmail settings:

settings > Accounts and import > Send mail as:
set another email which you want to use as from:

if you are using zoho then you can follow:
settings > Mail tab > Send mail as > add from address
then verify that email.

Answer (score 0):

For GSuite users...

What Jyohul said, is the correct way of doing it. You can add an alias in Google Admin Console, under "Users". Click on the user's name, and then click on "user information". In there you can add Aliases. Once the aliases are added, you can then do what Jyohul said, which I added a needed step...:

if you want to use different email address as sentFrom, then you can set your email from gmail settings:

Go to your Gmail, then click the gear on the top right, then:

settings > Accounts > Send mail as: then click "Add another email address".

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade to the latest version of PHPMailler. You should also make sure that you turn on debuging in oder to view erro messages.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

You will the identify the error. Also make sure your SMTP Server credentials are correct. Like host, username and password.
Mine worked correctly