# SetFrom PHPMailer not working in MYDOMAIN

Tags: email, sendmail, phpmailer

I have referred below links,

[SetFrom PHPMailer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085865/setfrom-phpmailer-not-working)

[PHPMailer - gmail smtp not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336402/phpmailer-gmail-smtp-not-working-properly)

But I my case I am send email,
    $mail->Username = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("abcd@xxx.com");

But still, when i send email it's showing my xxxx@xxxx.com";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those links say, if you send through gmail, you can't set anything but a gmail address as your form address unless they are handling mail for your domain or you configure "send mail as".

Comment: I am sending mail from my domain(xxx@xxx.com) not from gmail. In this case how I need to show the email which is in setFrom ?

Comment: You don't say where it's saying this, in what client etc. It would help if you posted headers of a received message. You may need to set the `Sender` property to be the same as your from address.